# Alternativa de winsound para Linux/Unix

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, unix

hace mucho que no ando por la comunidad de stackoverflow.

En este caso quiero saber si hay alguna alternativa standar en python para el modulo winsound de Windows.Pero en linux

**en resumen:**

una alternativa de Linux a este codigo:

```py
import winsound 

winsound.Playsound("ding.wav",winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

**Atencion**
-Tiene que ser sin usar librerias externas,mientras no se usen mejor.

*gracias por leer :)*

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/simpleaudio/

Answer (score 0):

para trabajar con audio en linux tienes varias opciones: pyglet, gsstreamer y alsaaudio que yo conozca.
Si lo que quieres es no usar librerias, desde la linea de comandos en la mayoria de distros de linux tienes `aplay`, que es muy facil de usar:

```
aplay sonidoReproducir.extension
```

Para usar esto en python te puedes servir de la libreria `os` o bien de `subprocess`, te propongo los dos ejemplos:

```
#Con os
import os
os.system('aplay sonidoReproducir.extension')

#Con subprocess
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['aplay','sonidoReproducir.extension'])
```

Espero haber resuelto tu problema, un saludo

Comment: es que lo hago de pydroid no se si funcione sabes...

Comment: @MaykolGonzalesCueti no entiendo que quieres decir

Comment: pydroid es una aplicacion para celulares en la cual programas y piedes llevar tu codigo a android,de esta manera pydroid usa linux como una especie de emulador,para asi poder programar y lo intente y dice que Aplay no existe me imagino que es por eso

Comment: vale pues entonces instala aplay en el android. Esto lo puedes hacer con: apt install alsa-utils que ahi es donde esta aplay. Por lo que he estado leyendo hay una libreria llamada pyttsx3 que te permite reproducir ese audio sin acceder a la raiz del dispositivo.

Comment: he encontrado una libreria llamada ossaudiodev me podrias ayudar a investigar sobre esta?